# Check if element is in viewport only once, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to increase/decrease `margin-left` of my image inside `div`, when this `div` is in viewport:

```
function onScroll(event){
 var scrollW = $(this)
  $('div.my').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
                 var st = scrollW.scrollTop();
                if (st > lastScrollTop){
                    //when scrolled to bottom
                    $("div.my img").css('margin-left', '+=20px');

                } else {
                     //when scrolled to top
                     $("div.my img").css('margin-left', '-=20px');               
                }
                lastScrollTop = st;

                //need to stop here
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine, except I'd like to change margin once for 20px when scrolled to bottom and once when scrolled to top.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried if(st <= 0){//top} if(st >= $( document ).height()){//bottom}